# How to hide a custom field for non logged in users (wordpress/php)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm hoping to gain some education here. I have a custom field that shows links to PDFs. The field is "biz_links". Is there a code I can place in the functions.php file that will allow only logged in users to see that custom field? Basically I have this custom field on many posts throughout my site and can't go into every page to use a plugin shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

try to use is_user_logged_in function

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   // your code for logged in user 
  } else {
    // your code for logged out user 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it look something like this?    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   custom_field(true); 
  } else {
   custom_field(false); 
  }

Comment: Yes, something like this, use a condicion for show the custom field inside the if

Comment: Would this function go in the `functions.php` file or the `template` file that has the custom field?